# How can I apply geom_area defined by the y-axis?

Tags: r, ggplot2

Please, find `My Data` below. I have used my dataset `nd` with the two covariates as seen below.

```
head(nd)
           y lnd
1: 0.3479943   0
2: 0.3740154   1
3: 0.3996300   2
4: 0.4217426   3
5: 0.4403666   4
6: 0.4572609   5
```

I have produced this plot:

[image]

I have used this script:

```
ggplot(as.data.frame(ndd), aes(x = lnd))  +


  geom_area(aes(y = y), data = function(x) subset(x, lnd >= 0 & lnd <=10),fill="#2C77BF", alpha=0.3) +
  geom_area(aes(y = y), data = function(x) subset(x, lnd >= 10 & lnd <= 25),fill="#E38072", alpha=0.3) +
  geom_area(aes(y = y), data = function(x) subset(x, lnd >= 25 & lnd <= 100),fill="#6DBCC3", alpha=0.3) +

  geom_line(aes(y = y, col = lnd),size=1) +

  geom_segment(aes(x = 0, y = 0.3479943, xend = 0, yend = 0.2), lty="solid", size=0.9, color="black") +
  geom_point(mapping = aes(x = 0, y = 0.3479943), size=4, shape=20, col="black", alpha=0.5) +

  ggtitle("", subtitle = "Risk") + scale_x_continuous(name="", breaks=seq(0,100,by=10), limits=c(0,100), label=c("LND 0% \nn=664","10%","20%", "30%", "40%","50%","60%","70%","80%","90%","100%")) +


  scale_y_continuous(name = "", breaks = seq(0.35,1,by=.1), labels=c("35%","20%-point\nincrease","55%","20%-point\nincrease","75%","20%-point\nincrease","95%")) +

  coord_cartesian(ylim=c(0.25,1)) +

  annotate("text", x = 5, y = 0.3, label = "LND 0 - \u226410%\nn=427", fontface=2,cex=3.5, colour="#2C77BF") +
  annotate("text", x = 17.5, y = 0.3, label = "LND 10 - 25%\nn=195", fontface=2,cex=3.5, colour="#E38072") +
  annotate("text", x = 30, y = 0.3, label = "LND \u226525%\nn=91", fontface=2,cex=3.5, colour="#6DBCC3") +


  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(colour="grey20",size=11,face=c("bold","plain","plain","plain","plain","plain","plain","plain","plain","plain","plain")), 
        axis.title.x = element_text(color = "grey20", size = 11, face="bold", margin=ggplot2::margin(t=12)),
        axis.text.y = element_text(color = c("grey","black","grey","black","grey","black","grey"),angle = 0, size = 11), 
        axis.title.y = element_text(color = "grey20", size = 14, face="bold", margin=ggplot2::margin(r=12)),
        plot.title = element_text(color = "grey20", size = 18,face="bold",hjust = 0.5),
        plot.subtitle = element_text(hjust = 0.5),
        legend.text=element_text(size=12), legend.title=element_text(size=14), legend.position="none")
```

As you can see, I received some help to arrange geom_area according to the x-axis `nd$lnd`, eg. `lnd >= 0 & lnd <=10`.

Now, I would like to do the same maneuver, but defined from the y-axis, eg. `y >= 0.35 & y <=0.55`.

I tried the following, but it did not work:

```
geom_area(aes(y = y), data = function(x) subset(x, y >= 0.35 & y <=0.55),fill="#2C77BF", alpha=0.3)
```

I would like it to fill as demonstrated on this photoshopped image:

[image]

```
My data

nd <- structure(list(y = c(0.347994323433218, 0.374015418531899, 0.399629966119251, 
                           0.421742599051725, 0.44036657229005, 0.457260948328608, 0.474417648309559, 
                           0.493640865541709, 0.51488973428659, 0.537423493454801, 0.560430703662936, 
                           0.583045245963954, 0.604403317363394, 0.624118977779026, 0.642197094829998, 
                           0.658675856783435, 0.673612299496595, 0.687077654264746, 0.699153267191595, 
                           0.709927163750076, 0.719491270455802, 0.727939260908065, 0.735364964416906, 
                           0.741861259442995, 0.747519368138831, 0.752428469501541, 0.756675554521809, 
                           0.760345455237322, 0.763520989282281, 0.766283171326885, 0.768711452044572, 
                           0.770883953521034, 0.772877677101532, 0.774768665456197, 0.776627848464512, 
                           0.778481560816502, 0.780330067279974, 0.782173296838651, 0.784011178693879, 
                           0.785843642275446, 0.787670617252314, 0.78949203354347, 0.791307821328959, 
                           0.793117911060613, 0.794922233473425, 0.796720719596049, 0.798513300762498, 
                           0.800299908622762, 0.802080475154149, 0.803854932672504, 0.805623213843368, 
                           0.807385251693197, 0.809140979620611, 0.810890331407796, 0.812633241231531, 
                           0.814369643674837, 0.816099473738181, 0.81782266685046, 0.819539158880875, 
                           0.821248886149957, 0.822951785441022, 0.824647794011433, 0.826336849604117, 
                           0.828018890458497, 0.829693855322157, 0.831361683462205, 0.833022314676256, 
                           0.834675689303694, 0.836321748237183, 0.837960432933643, 0.839591685425587, 
                           0.841215448331989, 0.84283166486968, 0.844440278864124, 0.846041234760886, 
                           0.847634477636162, 0.849219953207282, 0.850797607844881, 0.852367388582385, 
                           0.853929243127316, 0.855483119871763, 0.857028967903429, 0.858566737015336, 
                           0.860096377717062, 0.861617841244557, 0.863131079570552, 0.864636045414574, 
                           0.866132692253169, 0.867620974331152, 0.869100846667809, 0.870572265071487, 
                           0.872035186145084, 0.873489567298754, 0.874935366756863, 0.87637254356889, 
                           0.877801057617996, 0.879220869629812, 0.8806319411832, 0.882034234714961, 
                           0.883427713533749, 0.884812341823933), lnd = c(0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 
                                                                          5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 
                                                                          22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 
                                                                          38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50, 51, 52, 53, 
                                                                          54, 55, 56, 57, 58, 59, 60, 61, 62, 63, 64, 65, 66, 67, 68, 69, 
                                                                          70, 71, 72, 73, 74, 75, 76, 77, 78, 79, 80, 81, 82, 83, 84, 85, 
                                                                          86, 87, 88, 89, 90, 91, 92, 93, 94, 95, 96, 97, 98, 99, 100)), row.names = c(NA, 
                                                                                                                                                       -101L), class = c("data.table", "data.frame"))
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I used `geom_polygon` to add the area above the plot. I've also tried to rework some of the other plot code to get mappings from the data, rather than hard-coding them. It seems potentially misleading not to have the y-axis go down to zero, but I've left the y-axis range as coded in the question:

```
library(tidyverse)

cols = c("#2C77BF","#E38072","#6DBCC3")

# Function to add polygons above the curve
polys = function(xrng, col.num) {
  geom_polygon(data=nd %>% 
                 filter(lnd>=xrng[1], lnd<=xrng[2]) %>% 
                 bind_rows(data.frame(lnd=c(xrng[2], rep(0,2), xrng[1]),
                                      y=c(rep(nd$y[nd$lnd==xrng[2]], 2), rep(nd$y[nd$lnd==xrng[1]], 2)))), 
               fill=cols[col.num])
}
```

---

```
as.data.frame(approx(nd$lnd, nd$y, xout=c(nd$lnd, 10.0001, 25.0001))) %>% 
  set_names(c("lnd", "y")) %>% 
  mutate(xcut = cut(lnd, c(0,10,25,100), include.lowest=TRUE)) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(lnd, y))  +

  geom_area(aes(fill=xcut), alpha=0.3) +

  polys(c(0,10),1) +
  polys(c(10,25),2) +
  polys(c(25,100),3) +

  geom_line(size=1) +

  geom_segment(aes(x = 0, y = nd$y[1], xend = 0, yend = 0.2), lty="solid", size=0.9, color="black") +
  geom_point(aes(x = 0, y = nd$y[1]), size=4, shape=20, col="black", alpha=0.5) +

  geom_text(data = . %>% 
              group_by(xcut) %>% 
              summarise(n=n() - if(any(xcut=="[0,10]")) 0 else 1, 
                        rng=paste(floor(min(lnd)), "-", max(lnd)),
                        lnd=median(lnd)),
            aes(label=paste0("LND\n", rng, "%\nn=", n), 
                y=0.33, colour=xcut), fontface=2, size=3) + 

  scale_fill_manual(values=cols) +
  scale_colour_manual(values=cols) +

  labs(title="Risk") + 
  scale_x_continuous(name="", breaks=seq(0,100,by=10), limits=c(0,100), 
                     label=c(paste0("LND 0% \nn=",nrow(nd)), paste0(seq(10,100,10),"%"))) +

  scale_y_continuous(name = "", breaks = seq(0.35,1,by=.1), 
                     labels=c("35%","20%-point\nincrease","55%","20%-point\nincrease","75%","20%-point\nincrease","95%")) +

  coord_cartesian(ylim=c(0.25,1)) +

  theme_classic() +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(colour="grey20",size=11,face=c("bold",rep("plain",10))), 
        axis.title.x = element_text(color = "grey20", size = 11, face="bold", margin=margin(t=12)),
        axis.text.y = element_text(color = c("grey","black","grey","black","grey","black","grey"),angle = 0, size = 11), 
        axis.title.y = element_text(color = "grey20", size = 14, face="bold", margin=ggplot2::margin(r=12)),
        plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5, colour="grey20"),
        legend.position="none")
```

[image]

Comment: That is brilliant! I am working on it now. Thanks. Please, could you add the corresponding "red/cols[2] with y=0.55 - 0.75" and "green/cols[3] with y=0.75 - 0.95" to the y-axis too?

Comment: See updated answer. This could probably be reworked to get the polygon ranges from the data and use a single call to `geom_polygon`. The above approach, in contrast, requires some hard-coding, but it was quick to implement.

Comment: Yes, that is very close to what I am seeking, thank you for the effort. The last request would be to get the red and the green left border to align at nd$lnd==0. Please, could you help with that too? Thanks a lot.

Comment: That is beautiful. Thank you very much - this way over my level, so appreciate it. I cant even figure out how to change the alpha on the newest added polygons. Can show me? :)

Comment: In the polys function, add `alpha=0.3` inside the `geom_polygon` definition, just as you would for any geom.

Comment: Let me know if there are parts of the code that you find difficult to figure out and I will either add some explanation or point you to some additional resources for learning ggplot.

Comment: Sure, thanks alot - that is great. Perhaps, you know the answer to one of my other questions in relation to this plot? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59417478/how-to-alternate-text-angle-rotation-of-text-labels-with-axis-text-y-in-ggplot

Comment: I was looking at your script. I found this `y=c(rep(nd$y[nd$lnd==xrng[2]], 2), rep(nd$y[nd$lnd==xrng[1]], 2))))` in `geom_polygon`. How can I manually specify the y-axis? Eg the `blue/nd$lnd==0-10` should align with `nd$y==0.55` and not `nd$y[nd$lnd==xrng[1]]`. Similarly, the `red/nd$lnd==10-20` should align with `nd$y==0.75`

Comment: thanks again, sorry to impose. Please, could you help with the comment above in relation to manually align the individual polygons with specific nd$y values?